# Graphql Mutation types

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, mutation

Please help me, i want to include TriggerInput as varible inside my mutation declaration.
I am using react with apollo.
My mutation is like this:

```
addTrigger(
trigger: TriggerInput!
): Trigger!
```

with this type defined by the backend:

```
type TriggerInput {
name: String!
key: String!
sno: String!
enabled: String!
owner: String!
action: String!
analytics_opened: Int!
analytics_clicked: Int!
analytics_replied: Int!
analytics_conversion: Int!
}
```

usally i write mutations like this, by defining every variable type.

```
export const ADD_TRIGGER = gql`
  mutation addTrigger(
    $id: ID!, $name: String! ....
  ) {
    addTrigger(
     id: $id, name: $name ....
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

in this one the backend requires trigger as the variable with TriggerInput type, i am not defining the types of TriggerInput in my frontend. it works simply by typing TriggerInput!.
I want to understand why

```
export const ADD_TRIGGER = gql`
  mutation addTrigger(
    $trigger: TriggerInput!
  ) {
    addTrigger(
     trigger: $trigger
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Hi Nameless King, welcome to stack overflow! That error makes me think that there's an error in how you are _executing_ the mutation, not how you are _defining_ it. Could you post some details about how you are executing the mutation within your react components?

Comment: @JuanCaicedo
Thanks for replying, i edited the question.
I can use the mutation now, pls read the last part of the question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand your question now  It seems like the code is correctly using the TriggerInput Type. Could you try rephrasing the question, or adding some more details about what you're confused about?

Comment: I edited the question, sorry for not expressing myself well. I hope it's understandable now.

Comment: This is exactly the same as your original approach but instead of using scalar types that come with `GraphQL` you're using your custom `TriggerInput` input type.